# Raster calculator - problem with number variables in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

When I 'm calculating this expression:

```
("%Soil organic carbon (t/ha)%" / (10000 * "%Soil depth (m)%" * (Float("%Bulk density (kg/m3)%") / 1000))) * 100
```

Where:

"%Soil organic carbon (t/ha)%" and "%Bulk density (kg/m3)%" are **raster layers**

and

"%Soil depth (m)%" is **any value** or **calculator expression** with input values: **0.05, 0.15, 0.30**, etc.

[image]

I 'm geting this error:

> ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec()  Traceback (most
>   recent call last): File "", line 1, in   File
>   "", line 5, in rcexec   File "c:\program
>   files\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4483, in
>   Times
>       in_raster_or_constant2)   File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
>       result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4480, in
>   Wrapper
>       ["Times", in_raster_or_constant1, in_raster_or_constant2]) RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset
>   0.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.05   does not exist or is not supported
>
> Failed to execute (Raster Calculator).

Оn the contrary, when I write down "Soil depth" by hand like this, everything is ok

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you checked if all rasters are in the same projection? Are they all the same data / raster type (float...unsigned 8 bit...etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use quote symbols around numeric variables.  Using quotes includes the values as strings!

So, where you have `10000 * "%Soil Depth (m)%"`, this is equivalent to saying `10000 * "0.05"`.  NOT `10000 * 0.05`.

When you multiply a string by 10,000, you get that string concatenated to itself, 10,000 times!  Something like:

`0.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.05`... etc.  Which is what you see in your error message.

So change it to:  `10000 * %Soil Depth (m)%` (ie, without the double quotes).  The whole calculation then would be:

```
("%Soil organic carbon (t/ha)%" / (10000 * %Soil depth (m)% * (Float("%Bulk density (kg/m3)%") / 1000))) * 100
```

See also the [Raster Calculator documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) which states:

> Long, double, or Boolean-type variables will be enclosed in percent symbols (%%). They do not need to be in quotes.
>
> Example: %scale_factor%

Comment: Earlier, I was little confused after removing double quotes before and after percent symbols in raster calculator, because it showed me an `ERROR 000989 Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)`. However, everything worked just fine with that.